# removing view from superview crashing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile

I made a custom view that has a button inside it that would remove the view from its superview. The view is created from a view controller which is the superview. I have setup the constraints for my view in my custom view class as it follows, but i suppose they are problematic.

```
// View Contstaints
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 420).isActive = true
    centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundColor = .white
    layer.cornerRadius = 15
```

When i hit the button i get Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
from this particular constraint of the view

```
leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

How do i get around this? Thank you.

Comment: The custom view didn't add itself to its superview and so it shouldn't be tasked with removing itself from its superview. What I would probably do is create a protocol that contains a function like `removeCustomViewFromSuperview()` that the view controller (which contains this custom view) conforms to. When the button is tapped in the custom view, the custom view's delegate (which is the view controller) calls that method and the view controller removes that custom view from the superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you remove the view from its superview it might help to call `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(yourView.constraints)`

However it would be helpful to know where you are calling your constraint code inside the view's class. In general it's best to set up your constraints in the viewController, and then remove the view when desired also from within the view controller, that might solve the problem.

Comment: I tried it, it's still not working the problem is happening because unwrapping my superview while declaring my constraints to be related to the superview and as i am removing my subview i'm getting the error above.

Comment: As long as you activate the constraints in the viewController after you call `view.addSubview(yourView)` then the `superView` shouldn't be nil

Comment: Are you activating the constraints in your custom view subclass or in the viewController? From your code it looks like it is in the subclass

Comment: yes they're in my custom view class tucked in a function and i call that function by overriding didMoveToSuperview and calling it inside it

Comment: Ok I think I know what is happening. `didMoveToSuperview` gets called when you add your subview to a super view but **also** when it's removed. When it's removed the code is called and the superview is nil. You could just use a `guard let superView = superView else { return }` at the top of the function, but it is better to activate these constraints in the viewController immediately after you have added it as a subview rather than in the actual view itself

Comment: this explains pretty much everything, thank you. one last question i'm fairly to swift and ios development in general mind if i ask how do i exactly implement the guard let statement and if you could check my own solution to see if it's efficient as well

Comment: Glad we found out what the problem was. If you add `guard let unwrappedSuperView = superView else { return }` at the top of your function you can then refer to `unwrappedSuperView` wherever you use `superView!`. This way we can ensure that we're never going to be using a variable which could be nil (causing the crash).

Comment: Your solution probably isn't actually that inefficient but it's not the conventional way. It's best to make the viewController responsible for adding/removing the view. The view shouldn't be responsible for removing itself if the viewController added it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around it but not sure if it's efficient.
what i did is override the removefromsuperview function and removed all the constraints and subviews there

```
 override func removeFromSuperview() {
    for view in self.subviews{
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)

    removeAllConstraintsFromView(view: self)
}
```

Though I am not sure if by doing so I'm deallocating my custom view from memory